# Paypal Recurring payment profile URL

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to create recurring payment profile using direct payment. I'm using following url

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=**************&PWD=*********&SIGNATURE=*****************&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa&ACCT=4032031954635404&EXPDATE=122019&FIRSTNAME=Xylon&LASTNAME=Gracias&PROFILESTARTDATE=2014-12-30T07:05:09Z&BILLINGPERIOD=Month&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1&AMT=20
```

In the response i get the following error code: 10006.... version 2.0 not supported error... can anyone tell me if I'm passing the variables in the url wrongly? I'm using NVP

Answer (score 0):

A probable cause is that you are not passing any version parameter to PayPal (e.g. &VERSION=98) and PayPal tries to interpret your request through a version of the API which does not match the documentation you are using. See for example:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/release-notes/merchant/PayPal_Merchant_API_Release_Notes_98/

However, PayPal's error codes are sometimes very misleading; you may also gain insight by googling this error code and seeing what other people have done that generated it (e.g. making calls with missing parameters, or out of sequence).